# Python regex capturing before and after a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all the words before and after a given pattern in a sentence. Below is the code I'm using. Of course this is not perfect, so any suggestions are welcome.  My issue at hand is that, this is working for some patterns but not for others. For example, the given pattern below is not working, ie. re.match returns None.

```
sentence = "The agreements in this Section shall survive the resignation of the Administrative Agent, the L/C Issuer and the Swing Line Lender, the replacement of any Lender, the termination of the Aggregate Commitments and the repayment, satisfaction or discharge of all the other Obligations."

s = "commitments.*repayment"
rex = "(?i)((?:\\S+\\s+){0,30})\\b" + s + "\\b\\W*((?:\\S+\\s+){0,30})"
p = re.match(rex, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
print p
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Use `re.search`. The `re.match` searches only at the start of the string (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/P2SY61/2), remove `^` to see how `re.search` will do the job).

Comment: Show an example of working string with its result. Without that, it is hard to understand the reason for actual regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you, re.search does work. But what does start of the string mean? Since there is only one occurrence of "commitments", I expected re.match to work.  Also please reply as answer and I will accept this.

Comment: No, it is farther than 30 chars from the start of the string. Start of string *position* is meant. Empty space before the first symbol in a string.

Comment: Got it, thank you.